# odoo compose invoice from stock moves

Tags: xml, odoo, crm, odoo-11

I've been testing and searching for a solution to my problem but I'm not able to find any, thanks in advance to anyone that helps.

In Odoo 11 I'm trying to build invoices for suppliers from stock moves so I've added a tree view inside a notebook sheet to `account.invoice.supplier.form` that looks like this:

```
<field name="x_stock_move" widget="many2many" options="{'no_create': True}" domain="['&amp;',
  ('state','=','done'), ('picking_partner_id','=',context.get('partner_id'))]" 
  attrs="{'readonly':[('state','not in',('draft',))]}">
  <tree>
    <field name="state" invisible="1"/> 
    <field name="date" />
    <field name="picking_partner_id" invisible="1"/>
    <field name="reference" />
    <field name="product_id" />
    <field name="product_uom_qty" string="Cantidad" />
    <field name="product_uom" />
  </tree>
</field>
```

`account.invoice` has `x_stock_move`, a one2many field related to an invoice via `x_invoice_id` which is many2one in `stock.move`

My problem comes when (in account.invoice.supplier.form field x_stock_move) I click "add an element":
I can see all the stock.moves whose status is "done" and have the same partner as the one selected in the invoice but **I can also select the stock.moves that are assigned to another invoice** and this should not be possible.

I've tryied adding domain `[('x_invoice_id','=','False')]` to the field `x_stock_move` but this modifies the tree view inside `account.invoice.supplier.form` and not the "add an element" form, this way I can't add stock moves to invoices.

Adding `context="{'x_invoice_id':'False'}"` or `False` doesn't seem to change anything.

**What should I do to let a user only pick the `stock.moves` that dont have an `x_invoice_id` associated inside `account.invoice.supplier.form`?**

And here for **part 2**:

How can I add each record from `x_stock_move` as an `invoice_line_id` in the invoice I'm creating?
(I'd rather to do this just editing the xml view `account.invoice.supplier.form` or without having to develop a custom module)

Thanks for reaching this far and hope you have a nice day :)

**To simplify a bit I've ended up developing a module**, here is my model description:

```
class Move(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.move'


    x_invoice_id = fields.Many2one('account.invoice',
        string="Factura de referencia", ondelete='set null')


class Invoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    x_stock_move = fields.One2many('stock.move',
        string="Movimiento asociado",'x_invoice_id')
```

How can I add each `x_stock_move.product_id` and `x_stock_move.product_qty` as an invoice line?

Comment: Part 1 can be solved by just checking how to properly compose chained domains
`domain="['&amp;', ('state','=','done'), ('picking_partner_id','=',context.get('partner_id')), '&amp;', ('x_invoice_id','=',False)]"`

Comment: Can you please add the field defnition of `x_stock_move` and `x_invoice_id` python code here? You're mixing "many2many" and "one2many" in your question a lot. Wouldn't be better to create the process from "the other side"? I mean creating invoices out of moves (list) or even from whole pickings.

Comment: I'm not doing this by developing a module, I just created two new columns in the models
`account.invoice` has field `x_stock_move` type `one2many` object `stock.move` rel `x_invoice_id`

`stock.move` has field `x_invoice_id` type `many2one` object `account.invoice`

Comment: creating invoices out of moves sounds like a viable idea for part 2, I will try to find a solution through those lines

Comment: Your requirments will depend on a custom module, just saying.

Comment: I've finally went through the module creation but I'm not sure how to compute the addition of new invoice lines from this stock moves, could you help @CZoellner ? <3

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by a wizard that takes the active_id of the invoice when clicking on an action to open the wizard. See my below example (Not Tested but you will get the concept)

> stock_move_invoice_wizard.xml

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="stock_move_invoice_wizard">
    <field name="name">Stock Move Invoice</field>
    <field name="model">stock.move.invoice.wizard</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Stock Move Invoice">
            <group>
                <field name="invocie_id"/>
            </group>
            <group>
                <field name="moves_ids"/>
            </group>
            <footer>
                <button name="action_update_moves_date" string="Link moves to invocie" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                <button string="Cancel" special="cancel"/>
            </footer>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

and in the same file add the action to call the wizard

```
<act_window id="action_stock_move_invoice_wizard"
            name="Stock Move Invoice"
            res_model="stock.move.invoice.wizard"
            context="{'default_invoice_id': active_id}"
            view_mode="form"
            target="new"/>
```

> stock_move_invoice_wizard.py

```
class StockMoveInvoiceWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'stock.move.invoice.wizard'

    invoice_id = fields.Many2one('account.invoice', readonly=True)
    moves_ids = fields.Many2many('stock.move')

    def action_update_moves_invoice(self):
        for rec in self:
            for move in rec.moves_ids:
                move.x_invoice_id = rec.invoice_id.id
```

> account_invoice.xml

```
<record id="account_invoice_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">account.invoice.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="put_here_the_move_view_external_id"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//button[@name='action_cancel']" position="after">
            <button name="%(your_module_external_id.action_stock_move_invoice_wizard)d" string="Link Stock Moves" type="action"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```