# Odoo 11 insert one2many from calculated field

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I'm developing a custom module to allow users to create invoices with the information of stock moves.

In my .py I'm inhereting two models: stock.move and account.invoice, the target is to add new invoice_line_ids to the current invoice but I don't quite understand how calculated fields work. The code above is what I'm using

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import fields, models

class Move(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.move'


    x_invoice_id = fields.Many2one('account.invoice',
        string="Factura de referencia", ondelete='set null')


class Invoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    x_stock_move = fields.One2many('stock.move',
        string="Movimiento asociado",'x_invoice_id')


    invoice_line_ids = fields.One2many('account.invoice.line',
        string="Líneas de la factura",'invoice_id', compute='_add_lines')

## Add product_id and quantity from the selected stock moves
    @api.depends('x_stock_move')
    def _add_lines(self):
        for move in x_stock_move:
            self.env['account.invoice.line'].create({
                    'invoice_id': values['self.invoice_line_ids']
                    'product_id': values['move.product_id'],
                    'quantity': values['move.product_uom_qty']
            })
```

But the method _add_lines() is not working properly, any ideas?

here is my custom view

```
<odoo>
    <record id="invoice_stock_moves" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">account.invoice.x_stock_move</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_supplier_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">

            <xpath expr="//page" position="after">

                <page string="Movimientos asociados" attrs="{'invisible': [('partner_id', '=', False)]}">
                    <field name="x_stock_move" widget="many2many" options="{'no_create': True}" domain="['&amp;', ('state','=','done'), ('picking_partner_id','=',context.get('partner_id')), '&amp;', ('x_invoice_id','=',False)]" attrs="{'readonly':[('state','not in',('draft',))]}">
                      <tree>
                        <field name="state" invisible="1"/>
                        <field name="date" />
                        <field name="picking_partner_id" invisible="1"/>
                        <field name="reference" />
                        <field name="product_id" />
                        <field name="product_uom_qty" string="Cantidad" />
                        <field name="product_uom" />
                      </tree>
                    </field>
                </page>

            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by a wizard that takes the active_id of the invoice when clicking on an action to open the wizard. See my below example (Not Tested but you will get the concept)

> stock_move_invoice_wizard.xml

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="stock_move_invoice_wizard">
    <field name="name">Stock Move Invoice</field>
    <field name="model">stock.move.invoice.wizard</field>
    <field name="type">form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Stock Move Invoice">
            <group>
                <field name="invocie_id"/>
            </group>
            <group>
                <field name="moves_ids"/>
            </group>
            <footer>
                <button name="action_update_moves_date" string="Link moves to invocie" type="object" class="oe_highlight"/>
                <button string="Cancel" special="cancel"/>
            </footer>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

and in the same file add the action to call the wizard

```
<act_window id="action_stock_move_invoice_wizard"
            name="Stock Move Invoice"
            res_model="stock.move.invoice.wizard"
            context="{'default_invoice_id': active_id}"
            view_mode="form"
            target="new"/>
```

> stock_move_invoice_wizard.py

```
class StockMoveInvoiceWizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'stock.move.invoice.wizard'

    invoice_id = fields.Many2one('account.invoice', readonly=True)
    moves_ids = fields.Many2many('stock.move')

    def action_update_moves_invoice(self):
        for rec in self:
            for move in rec.moves_ids:
                move.x_invoice_id = rec.invoice_id.id
```

> account_invoice.xml

```
<record id="account_invoice_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">account.invoice.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="put_here_the_move_view_external_id"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//button[@name='action_cancel']" position="after">
            <button name="%(your_module_external_id.action_stock_move_invoice_wizard)d" string="Link Stock Moves" type="action"/>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: This is a way to do it but I want to build the invoice from account.invoice form

Comment: But you said "I'm developing a custom module to allow users to create invoices from stock moves." .. how are you going to now witch move to create the invoice for from the account.invoice you should be in the stock.move to have the move id

Comment: I've modified account.invoice.supplier.form to show all the moves related to the selected partner, i want that when selecting stock.moves they are also added to the invoice as invoice_line_ids

Comment: You can see a sample of the view im using here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66214835

Comment: So you just want to show the stock.moves in the invoice not create a new invoice for the moves ?

Comment: I want that each stock.move that is added to an invoice using the field x_stock_move is added as an invoice_line_ids inside the current invoice

Comment: Are the moves already created and you just want them to be in the invoice_line_ids ? or are you crating the moves from the invoice ?

Comment: Moves are already created, I'm just linking them to the invoice but i want them added as invoice_line_ids too (fields product_id and quantity)

Comment: Now i understand you. Yeah this can be done through a widget i will modify my answer to suite your needs .. what is domain of search in the moves because you are going to be lost in all of them (x_invoice_id == False is not enough)

Comment: You can check the new answer now @NachoR

Comment: what I'm trying to do is fix my method _add_lines() that I understand that will be called when x_stock_move is moddified, its someting along this lines
    


`@api.depends('x_stock_move')
    def _add_lines(self):
        for move in x_stock_move:
            self.env['account.invoice.line'].create({
                    'invoice_id': values['self.invoice_line_ids']
                    'product_id': values['move.product_id'],
                    'quantity': values['move.product_uom_qty']
 })`
but I'm not able to create the account.invoice.line and save it in the invoice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228770/discussion-between-nacho-r-and-amr-abd-alkrim).